# Lowercase all fields in an index during reindexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to re index an index and during this process i want to lowercase values of all the fields.
Is there any way i can do this.

Currently i have looked into the ingest pipeline but in it you have to name each field that needs to be converted to lowercase.

```
{
  "lowercase": {
    "field": "foo"
  }
}
```

I want something that can lowercase values of all fields without need to mentioning the name of fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to use scripting when calling the Reindex API. In the script you can iterate over all fields and lowercase their value. Something like this should work:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "target_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.forEach((field, value) -> ctx._source[field] = value?.toLowerCase())}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate.
Just one query it won't slow the data processing right if there are 3 million documents and 50 GB index size

Comment: Well of course it will. Scripting is always the last option to pick, but since you don't want to enumerate all the fields, that's pretty much your only option as far as I know. However, if you're running this only once because you don't want to reprocess the raw data from your primary source of truth, that should be ok.

Comment: Got it.Thanks